# Combine string and variable to existing variable (powershell)

Tags: powershell

```
PS > $Index = 1
PS > $Variable1 = "Var1"
PS > $Variable = "Variable$Index"
PS > $Variable
Variable1
```

Is there any way to have $Variable becoming the value of another variable ($Variable1) by using both string and yet another variable ($Index) to target it, something like the above?

Comment: You can play around with `(get-variable "Variable$($Index)").Value`

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed! If you leave it as an answer I'll gladly mark it.

Comment: done with a disclaimer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to explain your use case further because dynamically creating and using variables might not be the best solution.

That said, you can use `(get-variable "Variable$($Index)").Value` to start playing around and see how far it takes you.

Comment: Yes, It would be useful to know more about the intended use of the desired technique.  It almost seems as though the OP wants to something that is best accomplished by creating an array, and the referencing the array using the index as a selector.  But only the OP can say whether that is the real intent.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you are really trying to accomplish, you might find it useful to learn how arrays work.  Consider the following example:

```
$array = @("Var0", "Var1", "Var2")
$index = 1
$array[$Index]
```

The first step creates an array with three elements, and stores it in a variable.  Note the inclusion of the entry for zero,  before the entry for 1.

The second step stores the value 1 in a variable.

The third step uses the variable with value 1 as a selector to choose the right element in the array.  Note that if Index had been zero, it would have picked the first element of the array.

This is a very common technique in powershell,  but it may or may not be relevant to your use case.